# Two user prompts to open two files in one Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I need to open two files in the same workbook so I can preform some calculations on the values.

I can open a single file with the code below:

```
Sub sbVBA_To_Open_Workbook_FileDialog_xls_C()

    Dim strFileToOpen As String

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (Title:="Please select an Excel file to open", _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls (*.xls),")

    If strFileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open strFileToOpen

End Sub
```

I did find some code online that allows a user to select multiple files but mine are stored in different locations so it would be easier to have two prompt boxes.

It would help if I could load them into separate sheets e.g. `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: so 2  file-open dialogs would be needed?  or you want to pick 2 files from the 1 dialog box at same time? or is the 2nd name a variation of the 1st?

Comment: will they only be XLS files?  not XSLX etc?

Answer (score 1):

This will prompt for two `*.XLS*` filenames and open them both

```
Option Explicit

    Sub sbVBA_To_Open_Workbook_FileDialog_xls_C()

        Dim strFile1 As String, strFile2 As String

        strFile1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),", , "Choose Excel file #1")
        If strFile1 = "" Then GoTo userCancel

        strFile2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),", , "Choose Excel file #2")
        If strFile2 = "" Then GoTo userCancel


        Workbooks.Open strFile1
        Workbooks.Open strFile2


    Exit Sub

userCancel:
        MsgBox "User cancelled.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"

End Sub
```

It won't combine them into a worksheet but nore details would be needed about that. ie., how are they combined?  what if there's more than 1 worksheet in the source workbook?

...but these 2 can remain side by side

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Application.GetOpenFilename Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getopenfilename-method-excel)

Comment: Yeah I did, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The terms, "Workbook", and "File", are synonymous.  When a file is opened it becomes a workbook in the workbooks collection.  If you open several workbooks you can display their names with the following code:

```
Private Sub ShowWorkbookNames()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        Debug.Print wb.Name
    Next wb
End Sub
```

So if you have two different files open in Excel (Say, "Invoices.xlsm", and, "Download.csv") then running the above code will deliver the following output to the Immediate Window, which is viewable via ctrl+G:

```
Invoices.xlsm
Download.csv
```

You won't want to construct a third workbook containing one sheet from each of the first two workbooks, but that doesn't matter as you'll be able to access both worksheets in a similar way as you access two worksheets in the same workbook.

```
Private Sub IdentifyWorksheetsInSeperateWorkbooks()
    'Workbook 1
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("Invoices.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Accounts")
    Debug.Print ws1.Name
    'Workbook 2
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("Download.csv")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
    Debug.Print ws2.Name
End Sub
```

Running the above code will create the following output in the immediate window.

```
Accounts
Sheet1
```

And then you can do all the things that you normally do with the worksheets, ws1 and ws2, and remain completely oblivious to the fact that they are, in fact, in different workbooks.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty detailed response, I actually get the logic behind that now. I know my question was a bit ambiguous, but yeah basically it doesn't matter how they're open as long as I can work with them!

Comment: My pleasure.  If you find replies useful you can tag them as such.  I try to give a comprehensive answer because I've spent the last 6 months learning VBA from other people's questions on Stack Overflow, that have been answered comprehensively by other, kind individuals.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need more than 2 files to open, this will loop through the open dialog box, until you choose cancel or this X button on the dialog box.
You will need more code to do anything with the files after they are open.

```
Sub sbVBA_To_Open_Workbook_FileDialog_xls_C()

    Dim strFileToOpen As String
Do
    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (Title:="Please select an Excel file to open", _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

    If strFileToOpen = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open strFileToOpen
Loop
End Sub
```